# Get rows where specific column value is present between 1st and current row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate ratios between the current row and the 1st row. I will save the rows in another data frame, count the rows with value True and then count rows with value False and then find the ratio. It's like how the ratio changes with every new row.

One way to approach this goes like:

```
iterate between 0 to current row:    
        find_rows where name = 'X' 
        countTrue 
        return countTrue/totalCount
```

However, I think this is not a reasonable approach because I have a DataFrame of 4 million rows and the above loop will be calculating for every row. 
I'm looking for something like `numpy.cumsum` while having the flexibility to only use data between 1st and current row.

Sample DataFrame:

```
     name     attendance
0    X        True        
1    A        False
2    B        True
3    D        False
4    X        False
5    C        True
6    Z        False
7    X        True
```

Suppose I'm on 8th row, I want to have a look at all the previous rows and calculate `X`'s 'true' ratio

Comment: Can you send an example row?

Comment: @AshishAcharya added!